# SweetAlert and redirect if a condition is okay and after success message

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I am using the version 1 of SweetAlert:

https://github.com/errakeshpd/sweetalert-1

And my sample ajax code is as follows where i save user data.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "test.php",
data: {name1:name,status1:status},
cache: false,
success: function(result){
$('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
swal({
title: "Report Saved",
type: "success",
text: "The user details saved successfully!",
confirmButtonColor: "#00B4B4"
  });
},//success
error: function(result) 
{   
swal({
title: "Save failed",
type: "warning",
text: "We are unable to save data due to technical reasons!",
confirmButtonColor: "#00B4B4"
   });
 }  
});
```

**if status1 data == "Followup"**, i need to redirect the user:

1. after displaying the Success message 
   and
2. after user clicking the OK button.

How is that possible?? I am a newbie and trying to learn.

Thank in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a **callback function** to the `swal object` like this

```
swal({
     title: "Report Saved",
     type: "success",
     text: "The user details saved successfully!",
       confirmButtonColor: "#00B4B4"
  },function() {
    if(condition){
       window.location = "redirectURL";
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "test.php",
   data: {name1:name,status1:status},
   cache: false,
   success: function(result){
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
      swal({
         title: "Success!",
         text: "Please click yes to reload or relocate to the other page.",
         type: "success",
         confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
         confirmButtonText: "Yes",
         }).then((result) => {
             if(result.value){
                    //this is your success swal, after clicking the yes button, it will reload or go to the other page.
                    location.reload(); // this is your location reload.
                    window.location.href='somepage.html'; // this is your relocate to other page.
             }
        })
   },
   error: function(result) {   
      swal({
         title: "Save failed",
         type: "warning",
         text: "We are unable to save data due to technical reasons!",
         confirmButtonColor: "#00B4B4"
      });
   }  
});
```

I use Sweetalert 2 btw.

Answer (score -1):

```
swal(
title: "Save failed",
type: "warning",
text: "We are unable to save data due to technical reasons!",
confirmButtonColor: "#00B4B4").then(() => { window.location = "redirectUrl" });
```

when You click the Ok button, You are redirected to your specific URL. Replace "redirectUrl" with your desired URL

Comment: While this code may answer the question, including some additional details and information can greatly improve its long-term value, help others understand it, and therefore can result in more upvotes. Consider adding some explanatory text